# error:999 with Alchemy API to extract microformats

Tags: ibm-cloud, microformats, alchemyapi

I'm trying to use alchemy API to export microformats, I always have the same error

`cannot-retrieve:downstream-http-error:999`

Here is the call I use : http://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/url/URLGetMicroformatData?apikey=MYAPIKEY&url=http://fr.linkedin.com/in/laurentpauc

Any idea why ?

Comment: don't you have to encode the url parameter? (in this case, the linkedin link) -- see http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Answer (score 0):

well, I've tried here twice.

In the first attempt, it failed just like you've said.

In the second attempt, it worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
    <status>OK</status>
    <usage>By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html</usage>
    <url>https://www.linkedin.com/in/laurentpauc</url>
    <microformats>
        <microformat>
            <field>NameGivenName</field>
            <data>Laurent</data>
        </microformat>
        <microformat>
            <field>NameFamilyName</field>
            <data>Pauc</data>
        </microformat>
        <microformat>
            <field>AddrLocality</field>
            <data>Saint-Denis, &#xCE;le-de-France, France</data>
        </microformat>
        <microformat>
            <field>FormattedName</field>
            <data>Laurent Pauc</data>
        </microformat>
        <microformat>
            <field>OrgName</field>
            <data>ESPACE BUROCOM</data>
        </microformat>
        <microformat>
            <field>Title</field>
            <data>Responsable Marketing chez Espace Burocom &#x2022; Concessionnaire Xerox</data>
        </microformat>
    </microformats>
</results>
```

So I think this may be some temporary issue.